# react-native WebView session after closing IOS application

Tags: react-native, session, cookies, webview, header

I have a simple react native application with a WebView component for displaying my website based on php. So it works. But, when I login and close the application (on IOS), the session state was loose and I need login again. I know that all webview data like cookies cleared when the application close. So I need AsyncStorage to save all cookies to application storage and get it when application open for passing to headers.

**Here's my code:**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import CookieManager from '@react-native-community/cookies';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';


let domain = "[https]://mysite.com";

export default class WebViewScreen extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.currentUrl = domain;
   this.myWebView = React.createRef();

   this.state = {
     isReady: false,
     cookiesString: '',
 };
}

jsonCookiesToCookieString = (json) => {
  let cookiesString = '';
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(json)) {
    cookiesString += `${key}=${value.value}; `;
  }
  return cookiesString;
};

UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
  this.provideMeSavedCookies()
    .then(async (savedCookies) => {
      let cookiesString = this.jsonCookiesToCookieString(savedCookies);
      const PHPSESSID = await AsyncStorage.getItem('PHPSESSID');
      if (PHPSESSID) {
        cookiesString += `PHPSESSID=${PHPSESSID};`;
      }
      this.setState({cookiesString, isReady: true});
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      this.setState({isReady: true});
    });
}

onLoadEnd = (syntheticEvent) => {
  let successUrl = `${domain}/dashboard.php`;
  if (this.currentUrl === successUrl) {
    CookieManager.getAll(true).then((res) => {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('savedCookies', JSON.stringify(res));
      if (res.PHPSESSID) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('PHPSESSID', res.PHPSESSID.value);
      }
    });
  } 
};

onNavigationStateChange = (navState) => {
  this.currentUrl = navState.url;
};

provideMeSavedCookies = async () => {
  try {
    let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('savedCookies');
    if (value !== null) {
      return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(value));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return {}
  }
};

render() {
  const {cookiesString, isReady} = this.state;
  if (!isReady) {
    return null;
  }
  return ( 
    <SafeAreaView>
      <WebView
        ref={this.myWebView}
        source={{
          uri: domain,
          headers: { 
            Cookie: cookiesString,
          },
        }}
        allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        scalesPageToFit
        useWebKit
        onLoadEnd={this.onLoadEnd}
        onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
        sharedCookiesEnabled={true}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
    
    />
  </SafeAreaView>
 );
 }
}
```

> I missed all styles for most clearly and understanding code

So, I login and close the application. Then open again. It works only for one request, but not for multiple or when navigation. When I'm trying go to another page I loose my session and redirect to login page. If I change domain variable from `mysite.com` to `mysite.com/my-profile` where `/my-profile` page only for authorized users, it works too. My headers work only for first request page. How to fix it? How save the session after closing the app for each pages, not only for domain value?

Comment: Headers will be sent on the initial request only. But there is a workaround in the official documentations (you can track the current URL, intercept new page loads, and navigate to them yourself via state). You can follow this to achieve what you want: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#Setting-Custom-Headers

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to apply this example